# Interactive icon / .desktop

Tags: unity, icons, .desktop

I'm wondering if it's possible to create an interactive .desktop file.
An icon to a directory you can put on the desktop that changes when something is stored in the directory. What I want is create something like the trash can.

Is this possible with just a .desktop file or not?

I've been searching how the trash can works but did not find a .desktop file for it, found the trash directory and the trash icon, but that's mainly it.

Can somebody share a hint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented api for changing icons dynamically with unity but a hack-ish way of doing so would be to use `XChangeProperty`, a method provided by `libX11`.

An example I've found from a dated [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446847/xchangeproperty-to-change-icon-in-unity-bar-and-alt-tab-menu-and-window-of-runni?noredirect=1#comment42726597_26446847) links to a working [gist](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/a1541a6968d25ecaaefc) to perform that task using C.